# Passar duas váriaveis do Controller para view CodeIgniter

Tags: php, controller, view, codeigniter-3

Gostaria de passar duas váriaveis do Controller para view do CodeIgniter, segue código:

```
$lista_diversos['diversos'] = $this->diversos->getDiversos();
$listacodigos['codigos'] = $this->diversos->getCodigos();
$this->template->load('template', 'diversos/indexDiversos', $listacodigos, $lista_diversos);
```

as duas estão funcionando, quando eu passo qualquer uma delas como a primeira eu consigo pegar na view, mas a segunda não consigo recuperar na view, oque posso fazer?

Comment: vc só passa uma argumento que é um array com várias chaves.

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: `$dados['diversos'] = $this->diversos->getDiversos(); $dados['codigos'] = $this->diversos->getCodigos(); $this->template->load('template', 'diversos/indexDiversos', $dados);`

Comment: deu certo, valeu